# Javascript and Jquery | Share script without sharing the code

Tags: javascript, jquery

So, I have created my script with some javascript and jquery.
It's some code that you can run using greasemonkey/violentmonkey or even using it on a bookmark...
I want other people to use it, but I dont want to share my code. Is it possible? If it is, how can I do it?

Thank you!

Comment: At best you can obfuscate the code.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. What do you mean by obfuscate and how can I do it?
Edit - searching on it and looks cool... I'll see if it fits in what I need. Anyway thank you very much!

Comment: Refer to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obfuscation_(software) Update: Something like https://javascriptobfuscator.herokuapp.com/

Comment: No, it's impossible. Obfuscation and minimization is not enough.

Comment: See - https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=javascript+obfuscate

Comment: Thank you, it realy makes it hard to read... If there is no other way, this one will have to fit. Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can’t, only thing you can do is you can make it hard to understand.

For this go for **Obfuscation** and if performance is not an issue you can also go for **Base62 encoding** of the JavaScript. Which makes it hard to get.

You can check here for [Obfuscation](https://javascriptobfuscator.com/Javascript-Obfuscator.aspx) and here for [Base62 encoding](http://javascriptcompressor.com/)

There are ways where you can package your javascript in the form of image also.

[Check this](https://github.com/jklmnn/imagejs)

Comment: Thank you! Does this mean that if I use some javascript to load the image (that has the code) on the website, it will run the code I have inside the image?

Comment: check this interesting article https://www.patrick-wied.at/blog/a-technique-for-hiding-your-javascript-code

Comment: Still easy to get the code from the image... I think I'll have to take another path... Still tyvm!